# How can I use functions on fetched data with vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, fetch

im fetching data with;

```
data() {
  return {
    staffs: "",
    salaries:0,
    loading:true,
  };
},

methods: {
  async getStaffs() {
    const result = await axios.get(
      "/api/staffs/"
    );
    this.staffs = result.data
    this.loading = false
  },

  totalSalary(){

  for(var i = 0 ;i++;i<this.staffs.length){
    this.salaries += this.staffs[i].job.salary
  }
},

mounted() {
  this.getStaffs()
  this.totalSalary()
},
```

}

I want to calculate total salaries after fetching data and render it like

```
<span >Total Salary: {{salaries}}</span>
```

What is the correct way to do it? I don't want to use timeout or smt like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `async/await` in your `mounted` hook

```js
data() {
    return {
      staffs: "",
      salaries:0,
      loading:true,
    };
  },

methods: {
    async getStaffs() {
      const result = await axios.get(
        "/api/staffs/"
      );
      this.staffs = result.data
      this.loading = false
    },
    totalSalary(){
      for(var i = 0 ;i++;i<this.staffs.length){
        this.salaries += this.staffs[i].job.salary
      }
  },


  async mounted() {
       await this.getStaffs() // wait for getStafss to finish executing
       this.totalSalary()
  },
```

However, in your case, I would recommend using a `computed` prop to calculate `totalSalary`

Comment: Thanks for the answer,I made it with computed